# @Html.Hidden has wrong value when populating a div with the response from an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a simple view that contains a `div` with a partial view inside of it.  The partial view contains a list of items.  Each item is either shown in an excluded state (marked with XXX) or is shown with a button to exclude the item (which uses `Ajax.BeginForm`) to submit the `Id` and to update its state and redraw the list.

When the page is first drawn, it works correctly, however when the partial view is re-rendered after an Ajax call to exclude an item, rather than each item in the list having its unique `itemId` they all have the `itemId` of the item that was excluded by the form submission.

**Index.cshtml (Main View)**

```
@model IEnumerable<StackOverflowMvc.Controllers.TestModel>

<div id="modelList">
    @Html.Partial("ItemList", Model)
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**ItemList.cshtml (Partial View)**

```
@model IEnumerable<StackOverflowMvc.Controllers.TestModel>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <label>@item.Name</label>
            @if(item.Excluded) {
                <label>XXX</label>
            } else {
                using (Ajax.BeginForm("ExcludeItem", new AjaxOptions
                                    {
                                        HttpMethod = "post",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        UpdateTargetId = "modelList"
                                    })) {      
                    @Html.Hidden("id", item.Id)
<!--                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.Id" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
                }       
            } 
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I can get the page to work by commenting out the `@Html.Hidden` and uncommenting the hidden input (in which case the correct value is set to the id of the item).

What’s going on here?  Is there something wrong with the way I am using `Html.Hidden`, or the Ajax form?  Or is it just not supposed to work in this situation?

**HomeController.cs (just in case it's relevant)**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Excluded { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    static List<TestModel> _items = new List<TestModel>{
        new TestModel { Id=1, Name="Item 1", Excluded=false },
        new TestModel { Id=2, Name="Item 2", Excluded=false },
        new TestModel { Id=3, Name="Item 3", Excluded=false },
        new TestModel { Id=4, Name="Item 4", Excluded=false }
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_items);
    }

    public ActionResult GetItems()
    {
        return PartialView("ItemList", _items);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExcludeItem(int id)
    {
        _items.Find(x=>x.Id == id).Excluded = true;
        return PartialView("ItemList", _items);
    }

}
```

Sample output, to help illustrate the problem:

**modelList div on page load**

```
<div id="modelList">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Item 1</label>
<form action="/Home/ExcludeItem" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#modelList" id="form0" method="post">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="1" /><!--                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Item 2</label>
<form action="/Home/ExcludeItem" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#modelList" id="form1" method="post">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="2" /><!--                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Item 3</label>
<form action="/Home/ExcludeItem" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#modelList" id="form2" method="post">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="3" /><!--                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Item 4</label>
<form action="/Home/ExcludeItem" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#modelList" id="form3" method="post">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="4" /><!--                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**modelList after submitting to exclude item 2 (notice all inputs have value="2")**

```
<div id="modelList">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Item 1</label>
<form action="/Home/ExcludeItem" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#modelList" id="form0" method="post">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="2" /><!--                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Item 2</label>
            <label>XXX</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Item 3</label>
<form action="/Home/ExcludeItem" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#modelList" id="form1" method="post">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="2" /><!--                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Item 4</label>
<form action="/Home/ExcludeItem" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#modelList" id="form2" method="post">
                        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="2" /><!--                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4" />  -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact, that all the `input` elements have the same id/name (by the way having more than one element with the same id leads to an invalid HTML) and that ASP.NET MVC is rebinding the inputs based on data from `ModelState` not your model (this is mechanism which is by default used in order to return the form with values entered by user).

To avoiding binding from `ModelState` simply clear it in your POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExcludeItem(int id)
{
    _items.Find(x=>x.Id == id).Excluded = true;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return PartialView("ItemList", _items);
}
```

I would also suggest changing the call `Html.Hidden` in order to avoid duplicated ids to something like this:

```
@Html.Hidden("id", item.Id, new { @id = "id_" + item.Id });
```

This way your inputs should be rendered like this:

```
<input id="id_4" name="id" type="hidden" value="4" />
```

Which is perfectly valid and will still bind properly.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  Knowing the solution led me to  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx which has some good discussion around why it works this way.